# JSON Array Value Returns "[{"

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing a JSP web app and have converted a List of Java objects to a JSON array, and set it as an attribute. Right now I am trying to use JQuery to parse the Array and make separate JSON objects, but I have hit a big snag and can't find anything online where someone else has dealt with it. My servlet creates a properly formatted JSON array but when I access the value of the Array like so:

```
orders[0].value;
```

I get returned only "[{" in my JavaScript console. When I access the object

```
orders[0];
```

which is a hidden input that holds the Array, I find that the value looks like this:

```
value="[{"
                 firstname" : "John", "lastname" :                   "Doe", .....
```

As you can see, it looks like there is a newline after the "[{" and it is only recognizing it as the value. In the JavaScript console, the rest of the Array is highlighted differently as well.

I am totally stumped on how to solve that issue. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code from my servlet that sets the attribute:

```
Object orders = request.getSession().getAttribute("orders");

    String json = new Gson().toJson(orders);
    try {
        ArrayList<String> jsonList = extractObjects(json);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("jsonOrders", jsonList);

        //all prints on one line
        System.out.println(jsonList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("problem parsing JSON");
    }
}

enum ParserState {
    READING_OBJECT, READING_ARRAY
};

//create a JSON array
private ArrayList<String> extractObjects(String array) throws ParseException {
    ParserState state = ParserState.READING_ARRAY;
    StringBuilder currentObject = null;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    int parenthesisBalance = 0;
    for (char c : array.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case '{': {
            if (state == ParserState.READING_ARRAY) {
                state = ParserState.READING_OBJECT;
                currentObject = new StringBuilder();
            }
            parenthesisBalance++;
            currentObject.append(c);
            break;
        }
        case '}': {
            if (state == ParserState.READING_ARRAY) {
                throw new ParseException("unexpected '}' ", i);
            } else {
                currentObject.append(c);
                parenthesisBalance--;
                if (parenthesisBalance == 0) {
                    state = ParserState.READING_ARRAY;
                    result.add(currentObject.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            if (state == ParserState.READING_OBJECT) {
                currentObject.append(c);
            }
        }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's the input where I store the attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="${ sessionScope.jsonOrders }" id="orderData" />
```

when accessed with javascript using $('#orderData'), I get ,

```
<input type="hidden" value="[{" 
    firstname":"mike","lastname":"slagle","phonenumber":"17248802249","email":"[pslagle12@gmail.com]","duedate":"2016-11-24","product":"cake","comments":"this="" is="" 11242016="" 11.15","id":16,"price":11.15},="" {"firstname":"mike","lastname":"slagle","phonenumber":"17248802249","email":"[pslagle12@gmail.com]","duedate":"2016-11-24","product":"cake","comments":"this="" 11.15","id":17,"price":11.15},="" {"firstname":"patrick","lastname":"slagle","phonenumber":"7248802249","email":"[pslagle12@gmail.com]","duedate":"2016-11-24","product":"cookies","comments":"this="" cookies="" for="" patrick.","id":18,"price":15.66},="" {"firstname":"betsy","lastname":"horton","phonenumber":"7245443344","email":"[bhorton@hotmail.com]","duedate":"2016-12-17","product":"cupcakes="" ","comments":"this="" cupcakes="" bets.","id":19,"price":65.98},="" {"firstname":"morgan","lastname":"freeman","phonenumber":"864667234","email":"[freeman@hotmail.com]","duedate":"2016-02-15","product":"cake","comments":"this="" a="" cake="" morgan.","id":20,"price":200.75},="" {"firstname":"james","lastname":"boice","phonenumber":"7249983532","email":"[jboice@deadoldguy.net]","duedate":"2016-04-16","product":"cake="" and="" cookies","comments":"this="" an="" 18th="" century="" theologian","id":21,"price":54.95},="" theologian","id":22,"price":54.95}]"="" id="orderData">
```

And the way I am accessing the value which returns "[{":

```
var orders = $('#orderData')
console.log(orders[0].value);
```

**EDIT**

If I do this with my JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${ jsonOrders }">
${ i }
</c:forEach>
```

The contents of the entire JSON array are printed on my page, which is what I want. It seems that I'm dealing with some weird interplay between JQuery and JSON arrays. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped. The only thing that gives me a value from the array is orders[0].value, which gives me "[{".

Comment: Which library are you using to convert your Object to JSON ?

Comment: I am using the Gson library. If I print the String that is returned with println(), it all prints on one line. I will be editing the post with my code.

Answer (score 0):

where orders comes in this?? According to my view, i have seen json value is assigned to variable **value**.

json value is assigned like a String i.e `value="[{...}]"` , pls remove the qoutes and assign like this `value=[{....}]`

then access field values like  `value[0]["firstname"] or value[0].firstname` 
you will get the value **John**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orders = JSON.parse($('#orderData'));
console.log(orders[0].value);
```

Comment: When I do this, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".

Comment: how about try var orders = JSON.parse("{"+$('#orderData') + "}");console.log(orders[0][0].value); it might do not like json array "[...]"

Answer (score 0):

`value="[{"`

that right there tells you that `value` is not a JavaScript array of objects, but a `String` representation. You need to parse that `String` to get it into an actual `JavaScript` array that you can query.

Comment: When I try JSON.parse($('#jsonOrders')); I get "Uncaught Syntax Error: unexpected token o at position 1". Is there another way I need to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson` if you don't mind importing another library
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

```
session.setAttribute("jsonOrders", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(jsonList));
```

Then in the javascript do this:

```
var orders = JSON.parse($('#orderData').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to throw out this approach to getting my JSON altogether and instead am calling a servlet with a get request like so:

```
$.get('OrdersToJSONServlet', function(responseText) {
    ... 
});
```

It is working.